# Recursively searching through dictionary returning complete hirerachy

Tags: python, dictionary, search, recursion

My problem statement is I have search query and I have to return the dictionary matching the query maintaining the hierarchy.

I am able to achieve the first. But I want to return the 
complete hierarchy right from starting, like below

Getting this output:

```
{"Name":"google search","items":[],"properties":{"id":1,"process":123}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "items":[
    {'Name':'chrome','items':
     [
       {"Name":"google search","items":[],"properties":{"id":1,"process":123}}
     ]
    },
    ]

}
```

This is my sample input:

```
myinput = {
    "items":[
    {'Name':'firefox','items':[],"properties":{"one":1,"two":2}},
    {'Name':'chrome','items':[
                        {'Name':"stackoverflow","items":[],"properties":{"one":1,"two":2}},
                        {"Name":"google search","items":[],"properties":{"id":1,"process":123}}
                        ],
                        "properties":{"one":1,"two":2}},
    {'Name':'new','items':[],"properties":{"one":1,"two":2}},
    {'Name':'new','items':[],"properties":{"one":1,"two":2}},
    ]
}
```

This I what I have tried till now

```
matched_items = []
def resursive_fun(Nodes, searchQuery):
    for key, value in Nodes.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                matchValue = match_items(searchQuery, item['properties'])
                if matchValue:
                    matched_items.append(item)
                resursive_fun(item, searchQuery)
    return matched_items

searchDict = {"id": 1, "process": 123}
resursive_fun(myinput, searchDict)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to build your return value from the return value of any successful recursive call, rather than using a global list (which will cause all sorts of problems if you ever need to do multiple searches). You should return something with special meaning (like `None`) if there's no match.

Try something like this:

```
def recursive_search(data, query):
    if match_items(searchQuery, data["properties"]):            # base case
        return data

    if "items" in data and isinstance(data["items"], list):     # recursive case
        for item in data["items"]:
            x = recursive_search(item, query)
            if x is not None:                    # recursive search was successful!
                return {"Name": data["Name"], "items": [x]}

    return None                          # if search is not successful, return None
```

The `return None` could be omitted, since `None` is the default return value for a function that doesn't return anything else. But I think it's better to be explicit when the `None` has some meaning, as it does here.

If you don't just want to find the first matching result, but all matching results, you'll want to replace the early `return` calls with some more subtle behavior that only returns a value if a match was found somewhere:

```
def recursive_search(data, query):
    result = {}

    if if "properties" in data and match_items(searchQuery, data["properties"]):
        result["properties"] = data["properties"]

    if "items" in data and isinstance(data["items"], list):
        for item in data["items"]:
            result_items = []
            x = recursive_search(item, query)
            if x is not None:
                result_items.append(x)
        if result_items:         # recursive search found at least one match
            result["items"] = result_items

    if result:      # some part of the search found a match (either here or deeper)
        if "Name" in data:
            result["Name"] = data["Name"]
        return result
    else:
        return None
```

You could also return an empty dictionary on a failed match, rather than `None`. To do that, change the `if result: if "Name" in data:` lines near the end to the single line `if result and "Name" in data:` and do the `return result` unconditionally (unindent it and get rid of the `else: return None` block). Change the `if x is not None` check in the recursive case to `if x`.

Comment: This works fine. But If my search query matches more than one element in the input set, this algorithm doesn't return all the matches results. For example If the search dict is `searchDict = {"process":123}`, with this property two of my items having the same value. In that case, it should return me two dictionary with its hierarchy.

Comment: You can change the logic a bit to not short-circuit if you need to handle several matches. The only tricky thing in that situation is deciding how to handle the sub-items of an item that is matched. Should they always be included or not?

Comment: Sub-items not necessarily included all times. Can you explain bit more on how not to short-circuit to handle the several matches scenario?. would be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.